# SignalR call works but doesn't return to client

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor

I'm building a web application using Blazor, synchronizing teams (my domain model) via SignalR. (Blazor RC1 WebApp, core31 WebApi)

My client has a call that triggers the server to send the current list of teams to the client. This method has only two lines:

```
var currentTeams = await teamService.GetAllTeams().ConfigureAwait(false);
await SendTeamsToClient(currentTeams).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Those work - `SendTeamsToClient` takes the list and calls another SignalR-method on the client - successfully. The objects get sent to the client and handled correctly there.

Only problem is: The client-side call never returns. The client-side method has exactly one line:

```
await connection.InvokeAsync(nameof(ServerHub.SubscribeToAndReceiveTeamsAsync));
```

**And that one never returns. Any idea why?**

I have a workaround where I call that method as fire-and-forget, but that's really not a viable solution long-term.

I also tried letting the server call the `SendTeamsToClient` as fire-and-forget in case that was somehow interfering. Still, the teams get sent, but the initially called hub method returns on the server but never on the client.

## **Update (MCVE works, my project doesn't):**

So I tried to reproduce the problem, and I failed. This MCVE works flawlessly:

MCVE frontend, numbers indicating successful entries to console:

```
public async Task Ping()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sending ping..."); // 1
    await c.InvokeAsync("Ping");
    Console.WriteLine("ping returned."); // 4
}

public Task Pong(string p)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received pong: "+p); // 2+3
    Pongs.Add(p);
    StateHasChanged();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

MCVE backend:

```
public async Task Ping()
{
    var pongs = new string[]
    {
        "Pong1",
        "Pong2"
    };
    await SendPongs(pongs).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task SendPongs(IEnumerable<string> pongs)
{
    foreach (var pong in pongs)
    {
        await Clients.Caller.Pong(pong).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Actual project frontend:

```
public async Task SubscribeToAndReceiveTeamsAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Frontend Hub triggering teams"); // This arrives
    await connection.InvokeAsync(nameof(ServerHub.SubscribeToAndReceiveTeamsAsync));
    Console.WriteLine("Frontend hub done triggering teams."); // This doesn't
}

public Task ReceiveTeam(Team team) // Works completely (teams arrive in view)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Frontend hub receiving team "+team.Name);
    Console.WriteLine($"Invoking event with {OnNewTeam?.GetInvocationList().Length} listener(s).");
    OnNewTeam?.Invoke(team);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Actual project backend:

```
public async Task SubscribeToAndReceiveTeamsAsync()
{
    var currentTeams = await teamService.GetAllTeams().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Log(currentTeams.Count()); // This arrives with "2"
    await SendTeamsToClient(currentTeams).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Log("Server done"); // This arrives, therefore this method returns?
}

private async Task SendTeamsToClient(IEnumerable<Team> teams)
{
    foreach (var team in teams)
    {
        await Clients.Caller.ReceiveTeam(team).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

**No idea why one would work and the other wouldn't.**

**Quick update: It doesn't matter whether I use IIS or self-hosted. Neither work.**

## Update 2

Both MCVE and actual project use DI:

Frontend:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HubConnection>(sp => new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($"{builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress}signalr").WithAutomaticReconnect().Build());
```

Backend:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages(); // <- Not in actual project
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); // <- Not in actual project
            endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/signalr");
        });
```

I did however add a new method, and it has the same problem:

Frontend event calls `await connection.InvokeAsync(nameof(ServerHub.SendChatMessage), message);`

Backend sends it to other clients:

```
public Task SendChatMessage(string message)
{
    Clients.Others.ReceiveMessage(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
} // Debugger says this returns successfully
```

Others successfully receive the message.

Caller frontend invokation never returns.

Comment: Are you blocking further up the call stack on the client side?

Comment: No blockage whatsoever, except this call. There's a `Console.WriteLine` directly before and after this call, and the one after doesn't get called when I `await` the `InvokeAsync`. Further up is basically just calling this one and more `Console.WriteLine`s, starting from `OnInitializedAsync`.

Comment: I mean blocking like `.Wait()` or `.Result` *anywhere* further up the call stack.

Comment: Ah no, I have no blocking calls anywhere. `await` from top to bottom.

Comment: Can you post a minimal repro?

Comment: I can indeed not reproduce it in a new project. I did however put `Log()`s around the not returning method, and the method itself returns. Gonna look at configutation and try it without IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I upgraded my projects to .NET 5 and it works perfectly now. No idea whether it's about the framework or SignalR updates, but something clicked I guess?